# Set the SelectedIndex property of a ListView just after it has been populated

Tags: c#, windows, listview

I want to set the SelectedIndex property of a ListView to the value which was selected before the termination of the app.

So, just before the app is suspended, I save the SelectedIndex value.

Now in the OnLaunched() method, when I set the SelectedIndex property to that value, I get the ArgumentException, which says value not within the expected range. I searched for it, and found that the SelectedIndex property of the ListView was being changed before being populated (so the only valid value of the SelectedIndex is -1 at that time).

Ok, fine. But how to set the SelectedIndex property after the ListView is populated?

What is the easiest way? Should I dive into ItemsChanged events?

Update: Here's the code:

```
public sealed partial class MyPage : Page
{
    public List<String> myList { get; set; }

    public MyPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        myList = new List<string>()
        {
            "hello",
            "this",
            "is",
            "me"
        };                        //This is the ItemSource for the ListView
        ...
    }

    public void SetUpUI(int selectedItem)    //This method is called from
    {                                        //the OnLaunched() method
        MyListView.SelectedIndex = selectedItem;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Well how do you populate the ListView? as you say, after that is when you would do it

Comment: The ListView is populated in the constructor of the Page Class which contains it :/

Comment: Have you tried to do this on the `Page_Load` event? Or right after you populate your `ListView`?

Comment: myList in the above code is just a List<String>. This is set as the ItemSource property of the ListView in the XAML. So if I add the MyListView.SelectedIndex = selectedItem; statement just after the List<string> is populated, it will still give the same error (and I have tried this too). Also, please give a link to the event you suggest, because there are too many things which are named Page_Load on the internet :) Thanks

Comment: Try generate this event on your page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.loadcomplete(v=vs.110).aspx and then set your selected item.

Comment: `protected void Page_LoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // set your selected item here
}`

Comment: @NatanielRichardt thanks....solved by Page.Loaded event after all :'D...Thanks

Comment: I add this as answer so you can mark it as answered for future users search for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `Page.Load` or `Page.LoadComplete` event to set your selected item.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by using the Loaded event of this page, like so:

```
public sealed partial class MyPage : Page
{
    public List<String> myList { get; set; }
    int selectedItem = -1;

    public MyPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        myList = new List<string>()
        {
            "hello",
            "this",
            "is",
            "me"
        };

        Application.Current.Suspending += App_Suspending;

        this.Loaded += MyPage_Loaded;
    }

    private void MyPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyListView.SelectedIndex = selectedItem;
    }

    ...

    public void SetUpUI(int prevSelectedIndex)
    {
        selectedItem = prevSelectedIndex;
    }
}
```